# displayName get trimmed when using updateProfile with firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I was using firebase authentication createUserWithEmailAndPassword to create a user and used the updateProfile method to update the displayName of the user. Below is my code.

```
   const signUp = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(username);

    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    .then((authUser)=>{
      authUser.user.updateProfile({
        displayName : username
      })
    })
    .catch(err=>alert(err.message));
  }
```

The signUp function get triggered upon the user clicking the signUp button. The username display correctly in the console.
[image]
After creating user, there is another useEffect hook to log the authUser to console

```
 useEffect(()=>{
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser)=>{
      if(authUser){
        //user has login...
        console.log(authUser);
        setUser(authUser);
        if(authUser.displayName){
          //dont update username
        }else{
          return authUser.updateProfile({
            displayName : username,
          })
        }
      }else{
        //user has logged out...
        setUser(null);
      }

      return () => {
        //perform some cleanup actions
        unsubscribe();
      }
    })
  },[user,username])
```

The properties of the auth user seems to be displayed all fine except the displayName was trimmed. (The "test" was supposed to be "testing").

[image: The test was supposed to be testing]

Answer (score 0):

The call to `updateProfile` won't cause any changes to the way that your auth state observer works.  In fact, if you remove the call to `updateProfile`, I'm certain that the log will be exactly the same.  `onAuthStateChanged` is going to receive the initial user object that's created by the call to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.  Perhaps what you are seeing is an initial `displayName` value that simply contains everything before "@gmail.com" in the email address.

If you call `updateProfile`, and you want to observe the changes in displayName, you should sign out the user and sign them back in to get a new user object.  Or, even better, you can store the display name in a database so you can read and write it instantly.

Comment: I've tried to logout and login the user but the displayName is still the trimmed displayName. And also, the displayName is being trimmed not following a certain pattern, sometimes it trimmed "spongebob" to "sb", "Ben" to "B", which is really weird.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem was because the updateProfile is asynchronous. The displayName did not get trimmed anymore after I've converted the callback function into an async function.

```
const signUp = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(username);
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(async (authUser) => {
        await authUser.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: username,
        })
      })
      .catch(err => alert(err.message));

    setOpen(false);
  }
```